# How to hotswap PostgreSQL partitions with no interruptions?

Tags: postgresql, partitioning

How can I hotswap a postgresql partitions on a hot table with no downtime?

For example:

1. I have a partitioned table
2. I want to resync one of the partitions
3. I create a new table with the same schema as the partition
4. I fill the data in this new table
5. I detach the old partition
6. I attach the new table as a partition

However I'm worried that either:

1. I can't do this without an exclusive lock on the table which I may never get
2. If I use CONCURRENTLY then there will be a brief period between detaching and attaching where the partition will not exist for some queries

How can I guarantee it'll swap the partitions soon but also guarantee it won't be missing for any queries?

Comment: Why can't you do an UPDATE/INSERT into the existing partition?

Comment: You cannot do that without an `ACCESS EXCLUSIVE` lock, but the lock need not be long. This is only a problem if you always have long running transactions (but then you have lots of other problems as well).

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name this would massively bloat my tables and take a long time.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe thanks for the response. I guess this may be the only option. How does this work in a cluster with read replicas? How would the change propagate to replicas undergoing transactions?

Comment: @nick314 It will kill long running queries on the standby or delay replay, depending on how you configured the standby.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe great, thank you